# PHP Image Resize Classes

Tags: php, image-manipulation, imagemagick, gdlib

My website allows uploading of images. I limit images to 10 megapixel or less JPEG images, all images get stored in a directory. Now I want the images resized on the fly and I am looking for a PHP class/library that can do that for me. While I can write (and I have written) gd-library code for resizing images I want something that's stable tested and more importantly provides some kind of caching. I intend to use the script like this:

```
http://www.website.name/some-script.php?image=HPIM0001.jpg&max-size=600x450
```

Any suggestions (do mention pros/cons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) to do that.

Answer (score 6):

There's [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/), which is pretty good. Caching is AFAIK not built in, but that should be trivial to put on top...

```
if (!file_exists($filename . '_thumb.jpg')) {
    // Load original, resize, save to $filename_thumb.jpg
}

// serve $filename_thumb.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

Includes caching, probably will do what you're looking for.